# Magento create order programatically. getPayment()->importData too slow

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, programmatically

I'm creating orders programatically in magento but when I have to assign the payment method it will takes 10 to 50 minutes. I use:

```
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'banktransfer'));
```

Is posible to avoid the import data stament and use preformated array like in billing address, see example:

```
$addressData = array(
        'firstname' => $customer->getFirstname(),
        'lastname' => $customer->getLastname(),
        'street' => $pedido->ID,
        'city' => 'Ciudad',
        'postcode' => '123456',
        'telephone' => '123456',
        'country_id' => 'ES',
        'region_id' => 12, // id de la tabla directory_country_region
);
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);
```

Any idea about the payment array fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addData` instead of `importData`.

Comment: addData take the same time as importData. Probably the problem is that I have more than 170 cart rules and I supose that when I apply the payment method, probably the cart apply the rules. But If I make the order using the admin area the cart dont take too many time to apply cart rules. Programatically about 40 minutes for a order of 20 items and in admin area 5 minutes for the same order. THANKS!